# Can the FOR XML AUTO clause give unexpected results compared to normal sets of rows?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by, distinct, for-xml

I'm trying to understand some anomolies in my SQL results when returning with FOR XML AUTO. Strangely, I get different results in XML. In short, the count of **Institutions** should always be 603 but the XML data gives me 3 different totals as shown in this set of snippets:
[image: XML returned for web application]

The ORDER BY below simply passes through the choice for ordering the result. To debug this, I ran the stored procedure manually (commenting out the FOR XML clause and created 3 "debug" tables suffixed by the SORT parm passed (Each result set contains 603 rows when no FOR XML AUTO used).

[image: Each result set contains 603 rows when no FOR XML AUTO used]

Hopefully, the problem is now clearly shown. Here is the stored procedure (the bottom logic where the @Sort value determines ORDER BY is most relevant I think):

```
    ALTER Procedure [dbo].[FLAS2_List_Awards_V4]

-- EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V4 2,0
(
    @Sort   int = 1 
                    -- 1 = descending order on TotalAmount
                    -- 2 = descending order on TotalAwards
                    -- 3 = ascending order on Institution
    ,@Range int = 0
                    -- 0 = no filtering 
                    -- 1 = < $1 million
                    -- 2 = < $5 million
                    -- 3 = < $10 million
                    -- 4 = < $15 million
                    -- 5 = < $20 million
                    -- 6 = > $20 million
)
As

CREATE TABLE #TempMarkers
(
    ID          nchar(6) NOT NULL
,   Institution nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
,   Street      nvarchar(255) NULL
,   City        nvarchar(255) NULL
,   State       nvarchar(255) NULL
,   Zip         nvarchar(255) NULL
,   Latitude    decimal (28, 18) NULL
,   Longitude   decimal (28, 18) NULL
,   TotalAwards decimal (16, 0) NULL
,   TotalAmount decimal (16, 0) NULL
)
INSERT INTO #TempMarkers
(
    ID          
,   Institution 
,   Street      
,   City 
,   State       
,   Zip  
,   Latitude
,   Longitude       
,   TotalAwards 
,   TotalAmount 
)
SELECT DISTINCT
        C.ID 
      , C.InstitutionName
      , NULL AS street
      , NULL AS city
      , NULL AS state
      , NULL AS zip
      , NULL As Latitude
      , NULL As Longitude
      , NULL As TotalAwards
      , NULL As TotalAmount
  FROM dbo.FLAS2_Schools2 C
-- where c.ID in (135717,434584)
UPDATE #TempMarkers 
    SET      Street     = x.street
            ,City       = x.city
            ,State      = x.state
            ,Zip        = x.zip          
    FROM dbo.FLAS2_Schools2 X  
    WHERE X.ID = #TempMarkers.ID
    AND
    X.InstitutionName = #TempMarkers.Institution
UPDATE #TempMarkers 
    SET     Latitude    = Z.lat
            ,Longitude  = Z.Long
    FROM dbo.ZipCodesPreferred Z                         
    WHERE Z.ZipCode = #TempMarkers.Zip
CREATE TABLE #TempGrants
(
    ID          nchar(6) NOT NULL
,   TotalAwards decimal (16, 0) NULL
,   TotalAmount decimal (16, 0) NULL
)

EXECUTE dbo.FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards @Range

CREATE TABLE #FinalMarkers
(
    ID          nchar(6) NOT NULL
,   Institution nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
,   Street      nvarchar(255) NULL
,   City        nvarchar(255) NULL
,   State       nvarchar(255) NULL
,   Zip         nvarchar(255) NULL
,   Latitude    decimal (28, 18) NULL
,   Longitude   decimal (28, 18) NULL
,   TotalAwards decimal (16, 0) NULL
,   TotalAmount decimal (16, 0) NULL
)
INSERT INTO #FinalMarkers
(
    ID          
,   Institution 
,   Street      
,   City 
,   State       
,   Zip  
,   Latitude
,   Longitude       
,   TotalAwards 
,   TotalAmount 
)
select 
    t1.ID           
,   Institution 
,   Street      
,   City 
,   State       
,   Zip  
,   Latitude
,   Longitude       
,   t2.TotalAwards 
,   t2.TotalAmount 
FROM #TempMarkers t1
join #TempGrants t2 
on t1.id = t2.id

--SELECT * FROM #FinalMarkers

IF @Sort = 1 
BEGIN
SELECT   Marker.ID
        ,Marker.Institution
        ,Marker.Street
        ,Marker.City
        ,Marker.State
        ,Marker.Zip
        ,Marker.Latitude
        ,Marker.Longitude
        ,Marker.TotalAmount
        ,Marker.TotalAwards
        ,Award.GrantNumber as GrantNumber
        ,Award.TotalObligatedAmount as GrantAmount
FROM #FinalMarkers Marker     
     LEFT JOIN dbo.FLAS2_Grants Award
       ON Marker.ID = Award.ID
order by Marker.TotalAmount DESC, Marker.Institution, GrantAmount DESC
for xml auto, root('root')
END
IF @Sort = 2 
BEGIN
SELECT   Marker.ID
        ,Marker.Institution
        ,Marker.Street
        ,Marker.City
        ,Marker.State
        ,Marker.Zip
        ,Marker.Latitude
        ,Marker.Longitude       
        ,Marker.TotalAmount
        ,Marker.TotalAwards
        ,Award.GrantNumber as GrantNumber
        ,Award.TotalObligatedAmount as GrantAmount
FROM #FinalMarkers Marker     
     LEFT JOIN dbo.FLAS2_Grants Award
       ON Marker.ID = Award.ID
order by Marker.TotalAwards DESC, Marker.Institution ,GrantAmount DESC
for xml auto, root('root')
END
IF @Sort = 3 
BEGIN
SELECT   Marker.ID
        ,Marker.Institution
        ,Marker.Street
        ,Marker.City
        ,Marker.State
        ,Marker.Zip
        ,Marker.Latitude
        ,Marker.Longitude       
        ,Marker.TotalAmount
        ,Marker.TotalAwards
        ,Award.GrantNumber as GrantNumber
        ,Award.TotalObligatedAmount as GrantAmount
FROM #FinalMarkers Marker     
     LEFT JOIN dbo.FLAS2_Grants Award
       ON Marker.ID = Award.ID
order by Marker.Institution ,Marker.Street, GrantAmount DESC
for xml auto, root('root')
END
```

By the way, each of the "DEBUG" tables had exactly 1117 rows regardless of how ordered during creation using the INTO clause.

Finally, here is a snippet of what the web app loops through (counting "Markers"):
[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows some numbers. How are they generated / counted? Did you take the generated XML and analyse it manually? Might be, that this is not coming from the query at all...

Answer (score 0):

Well this was a difficult problem for me (and why I placed a bounty) but the help I received was of little help.

I solved the problem myself. The gist of the problem is needing to add GROUP BY and strengthen the ORDER BY clause by adding Marker.Street (see snippet below). BTW, the FOR XML AUTO is perfectly adequate for creation of Award elements within Marker elements.

```
    IF @Sort = 2 
BEGIN
SELECT   Marker.ID
        ,Marker.Institution
        ,Marker.Street
        ,Marker.City
        ,Marker.State
        ,Marker.Zip
        ,Marker.Latitude
        ,Marker.Longitude       
        ,Marker.TotalAmount
        ,Marker.TotalAwards
        ,Award.GrantNumber as GrantNumber
        ,Award.TotalObligatedAmount as GrantAmount
FROM #FinalMarkers Marker     
     LEFT JOIN dbo.FLAS2_Grants Award
       ON Marker.ID = Award.ID
GROUP BY Marker.ID
        ,Marker.Institution
        ,Marker.Street
        ,Marker.City
        ,Marker.State
        ,Marker.Zip
        ,Marker.Latitude
        ,Marker.Longitude
        ,Marker.TotalAmount
        ,Marker.TotalAwards
        ,Award.GrantNumber 
        ,Award.TotalObligatedAmount        
order BY Marker.TotalAwards DESC
        ,Marker.ID
        ,Marker.Institution
        ,Marker.Street
        ,GrantAmount DESC
for xml auto, root('root')
END
```

The GROUP BY was added to each block of code based on @Sort values but otherwise there is no change to the code in the OP.

Answer (score -1):

For the snippet you provided, for ID#140652, it shows two awards as sub elements. In your query, it would show two separate line items for this record because of the left join. You would thus see 603 records. However, you have less unique Ids. XML Auto is grouping these records into a single record. As best as I can see, it's counting these records as a single which would lead to <603. Per the documentation, the "ORDER BY is required to group all children under one parent...Therefore, first  element is created and then the  child element is added to it" I would review the XML Auto msdn page to see which of these things is impacting you but AUTO may not be your best bet. The easiest would be to find in your xml, the hierarchy of each sort. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188273.aspx

Comment: Thanks for trying. The only other person hopping on to this after the bounty was totally unhelpful and actually rude. This was difficult for me and I was suspicious that something with FOR XML AUTO was causing it but in the end it was just data quirks which I needed to tweak my SELECT clause.

Comment: Interesing, since above you stated all 3 results sets had 603 rows and your xml example clearly showed a element grouping by XML auto that would affect your counts. I would like to see what data quirk you changed because I suspect most likely, you did something to avoid XML Auto element grouping.